# Can't connect to some WiFis, Linux on Macbook Pro

Tags: linux, wifi

I just recently installed Fedora 20 on my Macbook, with MATE desktop.

Everything is fine at home (WiFi WPA2, connects without any issues whatsoever). Today is my first day back at Uni with the new setup and I can't log in to my university's WiFis.

There's 2 WiFis here, one WPA-Entreprise and another "unsecured". The unsecured one doesn't require a password to connect, but as soon as you launch a browser and navigate to a website, you are redirected to a WiFi login page (similar to what you may get in some airports or other public wifis).

Both WiFis always worked fine for me on OSX, they also seem to be working fine for all the Windows users around me.

Linux is having none of it though. I connected to both the way I would connect to any network: clicking the Network Manager in the panel, selecting the WiFi I want, entering a password if prompted and launching my browser.

With both WiFis, it looks like he's eternally trying to connect. I don't get prompted with any errors. I would ask staff for help but my university has a policy of not providing tech support for Linux users (...)

Since I'm relatively new to Linux, I don't know where to start debugging this. I've found only one guy with a similar problem on Google, and there were no answers to his post from 1 year ago.

**EDIT, PARTIAL SOLUTION**

Thanks for the comments, I will investigate with `journalctl` tomorrow to see exactly what's happened.

In the meantime I have partly solved my problem. I need to reboot everytime I want to change Wifi. I can't change Wifi while he's awake. The solution so far is to switch wifi off, reboot, choose a new wifi.

I suspect this has more to do with the wifi card driver than anything else, just my wild guess though.

Future work here probably belongs to another thread, I will however leave this one up. If someone else runs into this problem they'll at least have a partial solution.

Comment: To clarify: You can't get to the web login?

Comment: As root, run `journalctl -flu NetworkManager` in a terminal while trying to connect. Hopefully, you'll see what's happening (or not) in there.

Comment: Please include your `wpa_supplicant.conf`, if you are using that instead of NetworkManager